# draw_networkx() in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am getting this error when trying networkx

```
networkx.draw_networkx(G,ax = self.axes)
TypeError: draw_networkx() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)
```

The code for the same is

```
G=networkx.Graph()
G.add_node("spam")
G.add_edge(1,2)
networkx.draw_networkx(G,ax = self.axes)
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong and how can I correct this.... 
The link for the function is [draw_networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx).

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is expecting the `pos` argument, to inform the drawing routine how to position the nodes.  Here's how you can use a spring layout to populate `pos`:

```
networkx.draw_networkx(G, pos=networkx.spring_layout(G), ax=self.axes)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: awesome.... really thanks a lot man !!! you saved me from searching for other solutions .... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

samplebias gave a great example.

If you want an even simpler way to do it for command line analysis or messing around:

```
networkx.draw_spring(G)
```

It's a built in method for drawing based on spring weights and honors weights so you can include stuff like:

```
G=networkx.Graph()
G.add_node("spam")
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=4.7)
G.add_edge(1,"spam")
```

And the 1-2 connection will be shorter than the 1-spam connection due to spring weighting. Very quick and easy.